# Why does this XSLT code display all attribute values instead of just the model attribute value?

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML

```
<cars>
    <car model="Focus" manufacturer="Ford" year="2000" />
    <car model="Golf" manufacturer="Volkswagen" year="1999" />
    <car model="Camry" manufacturer="Toyota" year="1999" />
    <car model="Civic" manufacturer="Honda" year="2000" />
    <car model="Prizm" manufacturer="Chevrolet" year="2000" />
</cars>
```

My XSLT (Why is it selecting all attributes of the car node when i just specified the model node?

```
<xsl:template match="cars">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="car">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@model">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Because of the default match rule.

Answer (score 2):

Because XSLT has [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#built-in-rule) that are applied in the absence of an explicit template. The built-in template for attributes is:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

that is the same as your explicit template for the `model` attribute - so all attributes end up being processed in the same manner.

If you want only the `model` attribute, then try:

```
<xsl:template match="car">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@model" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note that your other two templates are redundant, as they too do exactly what the built-in template for elements does.